# How to Refresh Unity Catalog Table MataStore

Tags: sas, delta-lake, databricks-unity-catalog

I am creating unity catalog tables on top of the ADLS delta lake. there is a issue with when i update or remove new column in my ADLS delta side, the table column not refresh into the table.

there is two scenario, i can see the column details in unity catalog SQL query editor but when we connected in SAS BI reports tools the new column missing.

I am not sure about, this is unity catalog side or SAS BI report tool side. kindly some one help.

how should we refresh the meta store in unity catalog as well as SAS BI tools side.

example of unity catalog table creation as below,

```
create table catalogname.shchema.tablename
using delta
location "abfss://container@storageaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/test/data/deltatablename"
```